# Try to parse BsonDocument - JSON reader was expecting a value but found

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to run the following code :

```
    var groupByTimeSpans = BsonDocument.Parse(
    @"{ 
    '_id' : { 
        $subtract : [ ' +
            { $subtract: [ '$created', new Date('1970-01-01') ] }, 
            { $mod: [ 
                { $subtract: [ '$created', new Date('1970-01-01') ] }, 
                1000 * 60 * " + sessionSize.ToString() +
          @"]} 
        ]  
     },  
     'count': { $sum: 1 } 
     }");
```

But runtime throw an error to me

```
JSON reader was expecting a value but found '$created'.
```

I don't understand why?

Comment: well the error appears to be correct when checking it against this site http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: Not sure what you are doing with that + sign on line 3. Completely unnecessary, and the ' before it is what's causing your problems. Both are unnecessary.

Comment: i remove  `' + ` but the error present yet

Comment: And you're multiplication isn't legal either.

Comment: Seems it works!! i remove illegal multiplication, thanks!